# Unable to click an element on element all

Tags: javascript, protractor

Unable to click on element all method. I am getting Object Object has no method filter. While researching I found out that it has to do with some strings. Please advise. Thanks

```
 var sflag = $('a[ng-click="flagPhoto()"]');
  browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(sflag), 30000, "not clickable");
    $('a[ng-click="flagPhoto()"]').filter(function(elem, index) {
  return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
    return text === 'flag for abuse';
  });
}).then(function(filteredElements) {
  expect(filteredElements[0].isPresent()).toBe(true);
  filteredElements[0].click();
});
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with webdriver. Please remove the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not selecting multiple elements with this selector. Only the first found element will be selected:

```
$('a[ng-click="flagPhoto()"]').filter...
```

Instead, use this:

```
$$('a[ng-click="flagPhoto()"]').filter
```

Comment: Thanks finspin. I am getting cannot call method bind of undefined error message. I thought may be getText is causing the issue and removed that $$('a[ng-click="flagPhoto()"]').filter(function(elem, index) {
    console.log(filteredElements[0]);
  }).then(function(filteredElements) {
  expect(filteredElements[0].isPresent()).toBe(true);
  filteredElements[0].click();
});
  });

Comment: Is it possible that `filteredElements` is an empty array? Try `console.log(filteredElements)` before `expect()` .

Comment: I used a different locator and it works now. Perhaps problem with the locator I used earlier. Thanks so much element.all(by.css('a.flag')).
  filter(function(elem) {
    return elem.isDisplayed(); 
  }).
  first().
  click();